# Why am I getting "DOM Exception 8" ,when using Jquery's unwrap()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

*I have this simple small peace of code which generate an exception : (only in chrome)*

> Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8

Scenario : If a user visited a `textbox` and didn't put a value , he will be notify  when `bluring`.
And the `textbox` will be wrapped with a `red div`. And if he clicks  - (in order to put a value) - the red div is removed ( by `unwrap` the textbox).

So

- I have a textbox.
- This textbox has a blur handler attched.
- When a blur occurs , I'm checking if a value has been entered.

  - if a value has been entered : everything is ok. nothing is done.
  - if not :

    - I  `alert` the user
    - I wrap the `textbox` , with a red border
    - I attach  a `click event handler` so that if the user clicks on the text box (in order to put a value )
      the border  disappears .

**The problem :**

When the user was *alerted* and a `red-div` wraps the `textbox` , **every time I click** on the textbox *(in order to put a value*) - Im getting the  exception  ( and obviously things are messed up)

**Question** :

`Why` is it happenning , and `how` can I fix it ?

The code  : ( [**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/ubagac/3/edit) )

```
$("body").on("blur", ".myTb", function () {

    if (!$(this).val()) {
        alert('you must enter something!');
        doWork($(this))
    }

});


function doWork(obj) {

    var t = $("<div class='divError'/>");

    obj.wrap(t);

 obj.on('click', function () {
        obj.unwrap();
    });
}
```

---

p.s.:

1) I want to *keep* the idea of wrapping an element with a red div and to remove it when  - user clicks (in order to put a value). (*because this is a small part of my plugin which already works like this*)

2) There is **no** problem in FF

3) chrome version : 25.0.1364.97 m

4) jquery: 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you wrap the input field multiple times. As soon as you test if the error wrapper already exists, the error is gone:

```
$("body").on("blur", ".myTb", function () {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
        doWork($(this));
    }
});


function doWork(obj) {
    var t = $("<div class='divError'/>"),
        hasError = obj.closest('.divError').length;
  if(!hasError) {
    alert('you must enter something!');
    obj.wrap(t);
  }
  //console.log(obj);
  obj.on('click', function () {
    console.log(obj);
        obj.unwrap();
        obj.focus(); // be sure to set focus to the input element
    });
}
```

Updated [test is here](http://jsbin.com/ubagac/14/edit).

Comment: how can it wraps it multiple times if every click I UNWRAP it ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir see updated answer, the reason is the same, do the alert only in case there is no error class div around the element. And in case you unwrap, set focus to the field

Comment: woo.... there is something strange. run your code in chrome and open F12 , and blur the textbox  , and then click twice on the developer toolbar on the html button element and go back to the jsbin , youll see it wrapps it twice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the blur event fires when you unwrap the input element. It's safer to use `.one()` in this case:

```
function blurOn()
{
  $("body").one("blur", ".myTb", function () {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
        alert('you must enter something!');
        doWork($(this));
    }
  });
}

function doWork(obj) 
{
    var t = $("<div class='divError'/>");

    obj.wrap(t);

    obj.one('focus', function () {
       obj.unwrap().focus();
       blurOn(); // enable blur event handler again
    });
}

blurOn();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ubagac/18/)

Comment: regarding this line :`$("body").one("blur", ".myTb",...)` if there's 2 textboxes. is it `one` for each textbox  ? or `one` per blur operation ( regardless of how many textboxes) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir It's one for each element that matches the selector.